# How to mix numbers with text using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a card that I need it to show the Average of a column in a text style
this is what I have:

```
VAR Cnt = [CntPram]
var AllCnt = [CountAllPram]
RETURN
CntPram + " of " +[CountAllPram]
```

I end up getting this error
Cannot convert value 'of' of type Text to type Number.

How can I convert the numbers to make the card work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONCATENATE` for this.

**Syntax**

```
CONCATENATE(<text1>, <text2>)
```

This function joins two text strings into one text string. The joined items can be text, numbers or Boolean values represented as text, or a combination of those items. You can also use a column reference if the column contains appropriate values.

Read more on [CONCATENATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenate-function-dax)

Comment: Thank you but with concatenate I get this error.
Too many arguments were passed to the CONCATENATE function. The maximum argument count for the function is 2.
I have 3 text parts

Comment: @Sam332 You can use this. `CONCATENATE(<text1>, CONCATENATE(" of ", <text2>))`

Answer (score 0):

DAX does not recognize `+` as a concatenation operand for text srings. You can use nested `CONCATENATE` or join the strings using `&`:

```
Measure :=
[CntPram] & " of " & [CountAllPram]
```